# Run X11 on a server without a graphics card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on a mythtv server, something which just sits in the corner of the garage. Now I want to remove the graphic card because it's basically just using power for nothing.

However: I still want to vnc into the system from time to time. Should something go really bad, I would like to put the card back in and take a look with a physical monitor.

So: is there some kind of "virtual graphics card" I can use?

Or is there some other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

A VNC server effectively is a virtual graphics card.  You can run vncserver on a linux server, and then when you use a vnc viewer to connect to it, you can run any X11 apps, or even an entire desktop environment.

So yes you can.  Take out the graphics card, make sure vncserver is running as a service.